# Access denied for user 'username' to database 'dbname'

Tags: mysql

I am using godaddy as a host provider. 
I have a wordpress database setup that I am connecting to through asp.net and .Net Connector.
My initial connection to the db was fine, but I just started doing my first queries of the data and I'm now getting the above [Access denied for user 'username' to database 'dbname']

Everything I've read suggests that it's more than likely an issue with not having LOCK TABLES permissions for my specific user. I've tried some searching around and everything I've found from here suggests that I log in through SSH and type some schnazzy commands and all should be fine. However I'm not sure if I can even do that on my end with a godaddy basic hosting plan.

My question is, couldn't I just login to the database itself and in the Information_Schema section create the privilege record for my user?

Here's a quick look at the schema.

[image: Schema]

also here is a quick look at the table in particular which I imagine would be where I would need to add my record.

[image: Table Structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; madness that way lies.

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html):

> The permissible length for user names cannot be changed by altering the
>   mysql.user table. Attempting to do so results in unpredictable
>   behavior which may even make it impossible for users to log in to the
>   MySQL server. **You should never alter any of the tables in the mysql
>   database in any manner whatsoever except by means of the procedure
>   described in Section 4.4.9, “mysql_upgrade — Check Tables for MySQL
>   Upgrade”.**

Otherwise you're relying on very specific guarantees that were never given.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the permissable length for usernames has to do with my question. Going over to the manual was helpful, but i tried running a

    GRANT SELECT ON database.* TO user@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

and got the exact same error I got before, Access denied etc.

Comment: @DylanHayes: Read the quotation again. Permissable length for usernames happened to be the topic of the page, on which a warning was given -- which I even wrote in bold for you so that you could find it easily -- that you should not mess with MySQL's metatables.

Comment: Ah ok, it was late last evenin and I was frustrated with trying to get this to work. The bolded text does certainly give a clear warning to stay away from manually editing those metatables. However my root issue still exists which is an issue with my root user not having any privileges in my mysql wordpress database, and I'm still not sure if there is anything I can do about it... godaddy has a phpMyAdmin console that I do have access to write sql in, which ive tried doing a GRANT on my root user, Access denied, no privilege, I tried creating a new user, Access denied, no privilege...

Comment: I'm going to give you the +1 on this, you did answer the initial part of my question in regards to the metadata tables. I ended up figuring out the second part of my issue which was real a real dumb config file issue.... SO all in all, your post taught me to stay away from just manually adding the records myself and to use the Grant syntax. Thk you.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problem with your GRANTS.

If you are connecting to the database from anywhere other than localhost (SSH tunneling aside for a minute) then you'll need to log into you MySQL Db as root and run:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT SELECT ON database.* TO user@'%';
```

You should then be able to connect to the database as that user and select data from all of the tables in the `database` schema.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that my root user does not seem to have permissions to do any of this, i can't GRANT, I cant CREATE USER, I get the Access denied - you need privilege for this operation.